# Hortonworks HDP 2.x Java error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run the following command but I am getting the below error Could anyone explain it to me

`hdfs fsck / -files -blocks -locations > dfs-new-fsck-1.log`

I am trying to install Hortonworks HDP2.x

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "hortonworks-sandbox.localdomain/10.238.149.109"; destination host is: "hortonworks-sandbox.localdomain":8020; 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "hortonworks-sandbox.localdomain/10.238.149.109"; destination host is: "hortonworks-sandbox.localdomain":8020;
```

Answer (score 0):

Running *hdfs fsck* is a privileged task.  You must be the same user that is currently running the Hadoop namenode and datanode tasks in order to do this.

I suspect you have logged into the Hortonworks sandbox VM as the default root user.  You need to become the hdfs to run this command.

If you've logged in as root, you can become the hdfs user by doing the following:

```
su - hdfs
hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -locations
```

alternatively, you can do the following as root:

```
su - hdfs -c "hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -locations"
```

This allows you to run the command once as hdfs.

Finally, I see that you're using the default SIMPLE security mode.  If you were using Kerberos, you could need to get the appropriate kerberos key for the hdfs user.  In this case, you probably don't need to attempt that.